# Can't connect to mysql using node express

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I'm trying to connect to mysql using express but I cannot get it to work. I've searched similar questions but couldn't find the correct one for me. Right know I have this simple code:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var mysql = require('mysql');

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: ''
});

connection.connect((err) => {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("Connected");
    }
});

var authRouter = require('./routes/login');
var homeRouter = require('./routes/home');

var app = express();

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use('/', authRouter);
app.use('/', homeRouter);

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Running on port 3000");
})
```

I simply installed mysql using npm and tried to run the code. I keep getting **Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.**

It doesn't even log the error on `const connection = mysql.createConnection`

Tried using XAMPP but I get the same error.

Any help would be really appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried connecting to it from the cli? `mysql -u root -p `?

Comment: I had to install brew to connect from the cli and it connects but now on my terminal i get Error: ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE

Comment: So I'm not very well versed with MySql specifically but if I'd get that in SQL Server, it would mean that the DB I'm trying to connect to doesn't have user/pwd enabled: just domain user login. Maybe a Google on that error can help you, I'm sure it's not an unusual one.

Comment: Thanks for your time, but I managed to get it to work! I guess there was some problems with Express, had to make a separate file and require the connection on app.js.